# Running shiny apps in RStudio when proxying with nginx

Tags: r, nginx, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to use RStudio server proxied through nginx to develop a shiny app. When I use RStudio (not server) to run the shiny app, things work just fine.  However, when I run things through the proxied RStudio, the app appears in the "viewer" pane but the app is not functional. My console reports that the app is running on localhost:3691. Do I need to proxy that port, also, or is the websocket system that runs shiny not going to work through the nginx proxy?

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a how-to documentation on the Rstudio website that details how to use either Nginx or Apache reverse proxies.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552326-Running-RStudio-Server-with-a-Proxy

In particular it mentions *"you will also need to include code to correctly proxy websockets in order to correctly proxy Shiny apps and R Markdown documents within RStudio Server."*

Answer (score 0):

To make Shiny Apps work in RStudio Server Pro websocket support in NGINX is needed
. See also the [RStudio documentation article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552326-Running-RStudio-Server-with-a-Proxy) about this (which unfortunately does not specifically list which settings relate to the websocket support.

The important bits are:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
 default upgrade;
 '' close;
}
```

At the top of the NGINX config file.

And

```
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
```

In the `location {}` block of RStudio Server Pro.