# R Shiny app returning 404 when using NGINX as reverse proxy

Tags: r, nginx, shiny

I can run an R Shiny app locally using something like this:

```sh
R -e "shiny::runExample('01_hello', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3001L)
```

and then access that anywhere on my local network by visiting `<ip-address>:3001`.  I would then typically add a location directive in NGINX as follows:

```
  ...

  location /hello {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
   }

  ...
```

However, while I can visit `http://<ip-address>:3001`, when I try `http://<ip-address>/hello` I get a 404.  I've done this many times in the past, and the same setup is still working for other (non-Shiny) applications.  If anybody else has a similar thing working, I'd be keen to hear about it.

(Note that I am explicitly not talking about Shiny Server--I have  an instance of  Shiny Server running via NGINX without issue).

Edit:  Markdown was getting inlined in my comments, so adding here instead. I should note that my location directive actually looks as follows and is still returning 404:

```
  location /hello {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

I hadn't put the following in the http block, though, so tried it:

```
http {
  ...

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
  }  
  
  ...
}
```

I'm still getting the 404 error either way. I've been doing this for years (though the apps are usually running in Docker containers) without trouble, and this has only just started happening.  I think I'll try a vanilla setup with the app and NGINX both running inside a Docker container so I can rule out other config changes I might have made recently.

Comment: Shiny's communication is [based on websockets](https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/shiny-intro.html). As mentioned [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552326-Running-RStudio-Server-with-a-Proxy) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770707/9841389): `you will also need to include code to correctly proxy websockets`. (The article is about RStudio Server - But I guess the same applies to a standalone app)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, this doesn't work:

```
  location /hello {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
```

but this does:

```
  location /hello/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
```

It's really not clear to me why, but I'll go read the NGINX docs properly and I'm sure it will become clear.